# Group Numerical Data Within Specific Ranges

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I want to group the data from one of the tables in a SQL database. The field to be used for grouping is numerical and the groups I want do not follow any mathematical formula e.g.

Group 0 value unknown (NULL)

Group 1 values 0 - 499

Group 2 value 500 - 999

Group 3 value 1000 - 1999

Group 4 value 2000 - 4999

Group 5 value 5000 +

How can I achieve this with TSQL?

By the way I want to do this to display in a Crystal Report, so if there is a better way of doing this in Crystal Reports rather than through the SQL Select statement then please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` to create a custom group.  If you define the `case` in a subquery, you don't have to repeat the definition:

```
select  Grp
,       sum(col2)
,       avg(col3)
from    (
        select  case
                when col1 is null then 0
                when col1 between 0 and 499 then 1
                when col1 between 500 and 999 then 2
                ...
                end as Grp
        ,       *
        ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
        Grp
```